# Multiple ACF date-conditions via php array

Tags: php, arrays, field, advanced-custom-fields

Yes I'm still trying and no I still haven't found the answer.

I have posted multiple times on the ACF forms, I even created an official ACF ticket, I posted multiple times on Stack...

Really don't understand why people are not willing to help me with the few lines of code but I guess that's just the way it works :(

My final try and then I have to quit. Not because I want, but because I have to because the final key is missing to complete the puzzle.

What if I send you $75,- via PayPal (up front) would you then help me?

This working code:

```
// Apply conditions to fields
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=booking_time_session_1', 'yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions');
function yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions($field){

    if ( have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings') ) {
        while ( have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings') ) {
            the_row();
            
            if (get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_session', 'booking_settings') == '1' ) {
                $date = date_i18n('Ymd', strtotime(get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_date', 'booking_settings')));

                // Bail early if no option date found
                if (empty($date)) {
                    return $field;
                }

                // Add the condition to the field
                $field['conditional_logic'] = array(

                    array(

                        array(
                            'field'     => 'field_5ed4181bd63dc', // Time field session 1 in the form
                            'operator'  => '==', // If Value is different, then show the field
                            'value'     => '1', // Compare against session option page value
                        ),

                        array(
                            'field'     => 'field_5ed4178dd63d7', // Time field session 1 in the form
                            'operator'  => '!=', // If Value is different, then show the field
                            'value'     => $date, // Compare against date option page value
                        )

                    )

                );
            }

        }

    }

    // Return
    return $field;

}
```

gives me this data-condition output:

`data-conditions="[[{"field":"field_5ed4181bd63dc","operator":"==","value":"1"},{"field":"field_5ed4178dd63d7","operator":"!=","value":"20200625"}]]"`

20200625 is the last date (row) of 3 rows in the repeater field.

I simply want this part
`[{"field":"field_5ed4181bd63dc","operator":"==","value":"1"},{"field":"field_5ed4178dd63d7","operator":"!=","value":"20200625"}]`
multiple times separated with comma so all conditions will be active.

Can I hire you this? Someone with your knowledge of ACF should fix this in no time :)

If not... Anybody else around I can hire for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting here, SO is not a coding service.

But anyway, seems to me like you need to push your conditions, right now you are overwriting them - I have made a small playground here : https://www.tehplayground.com/YIO6KLfKfxVHFYRQ Where it looks like the format is correct.

```
<?php 
// Apply conditions to fields
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=booking_time_session_1', 'yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions');
function yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions($field){

if ( have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings') ) {
    //init the conditions array - When conditions are set, it need to be in array(array(array('conditions'))); format
    $field['conditional_logic'][0] = array();
    
    while ( have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings') ) {
        the_row();
        
        if (get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_session', 'booking_settings') == '1' ) {
            $date = date_i18n('Ymd', strtotime(get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_date', 'booking_settings')));

            // Bail early if no option date found
            if (empty($date)) {
                //set the conditions back to default 0
                $field['conditional_logic'] = 0;
                return $field;
            }

            // Add the condition to the field
            $field['conditional_logic'][0][] = array(
                        'field'     => 'field_5ed4181bd63dc', // Time field session 1 in the form
                        'operator'  => '==', // If Value is different, then show the field
                        'value'     => '1', // Compare against session option page value
                    );
                    
            $field['conditional_logic'][0][] = array(
                        'field'     => 'field_5ed4178dd63d7', // Time field session 1 in the form
                        'operator'  => '!=', // If Value is different, then show the field
                        'value'     => $date, // Compare against date option page value
                    );
        }

    }

}

// Return
return $field;

}
?>
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: So great full you are trying to help me out here, and if we're getting it up and running it sure is a coding service so I will pay you as promised. For now their might be just a minor error in the code because now none of the conditions come up. Its the field TIJD SESSIE 1 that needs the data-condition if you want to check: https://olddutch.yorlinq.com/reserveren - Hope to hear from you :)

Comment: Sorry - not really sure what is supposed to happen on the website :-D but you can try to remove the `$field['conditional_logic'] = 0;` since, if you have no date in your last row, it will reset the entire conditions field - I don't think I can help you much more than this tbh.

Comment: But at least, I see that there are more than one date in your site now `
2020-06-24,2020-06-25,2020-06-25`

Comment: I use CODE SNIPPETS for this so its easy to check and try. If you're willing I can give you login credentials (its a test site and when everything works we'll be rebuilding the live one so)... If yes.... How can I provide you the login credentials? (And if you want me to pay first... that's fine ;))

Comment: Have you tried something like https://www.justanswer.com/sip/coding/ - They might be better suited at helping you then I am. I honestly would not know where to start. Keep your money, start a trial membership with them, and get a dedicated "expert" person to help :) I wish you luck.

Comment: Unbelievable but so far you gave me the most attention even after using the companies above. 

Can’t believe it already took me allmost 2 weeks and still nothing. Is it such a crazy tough hard thing to do? I just can’t believe that. Even though I still have nothing... you are very kind m8.